# Cannot save filepath to database from c++

Tags: c++, mysql

I am trying to save an image path to a  `mysql database` from c++. The insertion takes place but the path is saved in this form:

**C:Usersakrs.aDesktopatch_1images 01aa1363659036.jpg**

rather than
**C:\Users\akrs.a\Desktop\batch_1\images\001aa1363659036.jpg**

so it is omitting `'\','\b' and '\0'`.

The code for the insertion in c++ is:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 2; i++)
{

     std::string imgpath=dresses[i]->imgPath->data();  //gets the path       
     std::ostringstream querydb;
     querydb<<"insert into base_table(imgPath,store,apparelType) values('"<< imgpath <<"','testdb','dress')";
     mysql_query(connect,querydb.str().c_str());
}
mysql_close(connect);
```

I tried to print out the `querydb` too and the `imagepath` is sent correctly.How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to use a parameterized query.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to escape the \ character.

Comment: Thanks can you please provide a small example in c++ using parameterized query.

Comment: where should I use the mysql_real_escape_string() can you provide an example or any helpful links.thanks

Answer (score 1):

try to replace all **"\"** with **"\\"** in "imgpath" variable.

Comment: I tried string.replace(imgpath.begin(),imgpath.end(),"'\'","\\") But I get an error expected unqualified-id before '.' token

Comment: actually you should try this: string.replace(imgpath.begin(),imgpath.end(),"\\","\\\\")

Comment: I'm wondering why you don't use forward slash. I think it works on windows too.